# Preparing CSV files for database import

Tags: php, mysql, database, excel, csv

Good morning,

I've been asked to work on some excel files that contain string or number data, below an example of what the file might look like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         ID        |       NAME      |    SURNAME    |  AGE    |    SKU   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|         1         |      John       |      Doe      |    120  |    1      |
|         2         |      Mary       |      Doe      |    121  |    2      |
|         3         |      Jane       |      Kit      |    120  |    3      |
|         4         |      Kim        |   Richards    |    100  |    4      |
|         5         |      Jong       |      Kor      |    100  |    5      |
|         6         |      Un         |      Kor      |    100  |    6      |                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The data is invented for the purpose of the question. Let's say I have 3 different CSV files, all with similar data inside of them.

The first CSV has the five columns in the example `[id, name, surname, age, sku]`

The second CSV has the five colums in the example with one more column `[id, name, surname, address, age, sku]`

The third CSV has just 3 columns `[id, name, surname]` and completely misses two columns from the example.

My idea would be to merge / combine all three CSV files into a single one, and when the merging is done, import all the data inside a relational database.
I have imported CSV files with PHP before, but never merged data together, so I have a lack of knowledge in this sense, specifically on terms and how-tos.

Considering that the three CSVs that I would be merging differ in columns, how would I go about merging them? More importantly, for the sake of future searches on this argument, what is the conventional name of this action?

I guess that the merging process would result in the creation of dummy data for the missing columns in the files. The CSV file would then have 6 columns, 5 being the first file columns and the added one coming from the second file columns (`address` from the second CSV). But what about the data?

Now I should have a file with the six columns, but what about the rows that didn't originally have values for the added columns? Taking in consideration the first and the third CSV files:

First CSV doesn't have data for the `address` column, Third CSV doesn't have data for the `address`, `age`, `sku` columns.

How would I give dummy data (like `null`) to those rows? What is the name of this operation?

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: I wouldn't merge these files into a new csv but in arrays. How big are your files? How are these entries matched, by id or by name & surname? The files seem to have redundant fields, which source should be prioritized? Why do you need the third file as it only contains redundant fields?

Comment: because all files contain important data which i need for data analysis. So I need all documents because they contain the same kind of data, alas, not all of them have the same headers / columns, that's why i wanted to know how to merge them safely, so that i could still import them into a database, some with the values, others with a "null" value because they didn't have it when they were created first

Comment: How big are your files? So these entries are matched by 'id'? Is it possible that these files files contain an entry with different values (not null) for the same field?

Comment: they are excel files with 8 to 10 columns with 500 records each, so i've been told. Values that do not exist within some of the files should be set to null so that i can import safely into mysql database

Comment: These entries from the different files are matched by 'id'? Is it possible that these files files contain faulty redundant information? (an entry with different values (not null) for the same field, for example one file contains name="Peter" and id=10, the other name="Jackson" and id=10)

Comment: nice question; the id field could overlap and be redundant, yes, but let's say that i can change each id field to be unique by rewriting all the id values with a letter before them so they become csv1id1, csv2id1, cdv3id1; i don't think redundancy might be a problem tho given that the information can be redundant as long as the number of the practice (which is a field they all have) is unique, and that much i've been told is unique, no matter the file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138129/discussion-between-fabian-h-and-mnemosdev).